# How can get the overflow menu option to be clicked using protractor

Tags: protractor

An overflow menu is using in the application:
[OverflowMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfMDZ.png)
I'm using Protractor to grab the menu and it's options, I can click and open the overflow menu but failed to click the options within overflow menu.

The HTML code for overflow menu and options:

```
<td class="bx--table-column-menu">
<div data-overflow-menu="" tabindex="0" aria-label="Overflow menu description" class="bx--overflow-menu" carbon-overflow-menu="" aria-expanded="false">
<svg class="bx--overflow-menu__icon" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" aria-hidden="true">
<circle cx="8" cy="3" r="1"></circle>
<circle cx="8" cy="8" r="1"></circle>
<circle cx="8" cy="13" r="1"></circle>
</svg>
<ul class="bx--overflow-menu-options bx--overflow-menu--flip" data-floating-menu-direction="bottom">
<li class="bx--overflow-menu-options__option bx--table-row--menu-option">
        <button class="bx--overflow-menu-options__btn" ng-click="vm.dealSelected(data)">                                       <div class="bx--overflow-menu-options__option-content">
            <span>Open Opportunity</span>
           </div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="bx--overflow-menu-options__option bx--table-row--menu-option ng-scope" ng-if="(data.accesslist[0].authtype | lowercase ) == 'admin'">
        <button class="bx--overflow-menu-options__btn" ng-click="vm.dealSelectedAction(data, 'app.modify-project')">
               <div class="bx--overflow-menu-options__option-content">
                <span>Modify Opportunity</span>
           </div>
        </button>
</li><!-- end ngIf: (data.accesslist[0].authtype | lowercase ) == 'admin' -->
```

...

In Web Developer -> Inspector view, I noticed that the code below tag "ul" is grey.

I verified XPath for the menu options by add-ons TX of Firefox, the XPath is:

```
//td[@class='bx--table-column-menu']/div/ul/li/button/div/span[contains(text(),'Open Opportunity')]
```

As result of execution, I got Count: 1 successfully

I'm trying to use following codes to grab and click option in overflow menu:

```
element(by.xpath("//td[@class='bx--table-column-menu']/div/ul/li/button/div/span[contains(text(),'Open Opportunity')]")).click();
```

I got error message:

```
No element found using locator: By(xpath, //td[@class='bx--table-column-menu']/div/ul/li/button/div/span[contains(text(),'Open Opportunity')])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the li item is grey it means the element is not displayed. Hence click is not working.
After opening the overflow menu wait till element.isDiplayed(), then try the click.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, when I followed your cue to open overflow menu under Inspector view, I noticed that a new HTML page was rendered, so the xpath showed above is expired. after refreshing the xpath, the option in the overflow menu can be grabbed. thank again!